# How do I pass AppCompatActivity to module?

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

I use Dagger 2 in my project. I have several modules in the project.
And I have a BaseActivityModule that connects to each Activity module.
How to get AppCompatActivity in BaseActivityModule.

**When compiling a project, I get this error**

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.app.AlertDialog cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
>   public abstract interface AppComponent {
>                   ^
>         android.app.AlertDialog is injected at
>             com.example.laptop.daggerexample.ui.main.view.MainActivity.alertDialog
>         com.example.laptop.daggerexample.ui.main.view.MainActivity is injected at
>             dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
>     component path: com.example.laptop.daggerexample.di.component.AppComponent ? com.example.laptop.daggerexample.di.builder.ActivityBuilder_BindMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent

**Example below modules in the project**

**ActivityBuilder**

```
@Module
     abstract class ActivityBuilder {
     @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [(MainActivityModule::class)])
     abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

**AppModule**

```
@Module
abstract class AppModule{
     @Provides
     @Singleton
     fun provideContext(application: Application): Context = application
}
```

**BaseActivityModule**

```
@Module
class BaseActivityModule {
     @Provides
     fun provideAlertDialog(activity: AppCompatActivity)= 
     AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create()
}
```

**MainActivityModule**

```
@Module(includes = [(BaseActivityModule::class)])
class MainActivityModule {
     @Provides
     fun provideMainMVPView(activity: MainActivity): MainMVPView = activity

     @Provides
     fun provideMainMVPPresenter(presenter: MainPresenter<MainMVPView>): 
     MainMVPPresenter<MainMVPView> = presenter
}
```